# Bash shell script to randomly run different files

Tags: linux, bash

Wondering if anyone out there can offer up a short shell script that will randomly go through a directory and then "exec" a particular file.  Essentially I'm looking for an mp3 shuffle kind of thing:

mp3_123.mp3
mp3_456.mp3
mp3_567.mp3
mp3_678.mp3

I could rename all the files so they're "mp3_1.mp3, mp3_2.mp3, etc." but I'd rather have it actually have (maybe?) an array of all the existing filenames, then pull out one randomly and play it on amarok or xine.  (I'm assuming the latter part would be "...| exec amarok mp3_678.mp3" or something.  But I don't know how to do the first part -- go through the filenames, make an array, then pull out a random array value and use that as the filename.

Any help would be great!  Thank you!

Comment: Might take a look at this: http://benjisimon.blogspot.com/2008/05/bash-shell-hack-picking-random-set-of.html or piping out to `sort -R` (note: GNU sort only)

Comment: Hey, thanks -- this ALMOST works (actually, there's a comment that's better...("ls | sort -R | head -n1" is exactly what I need, but how do I then get amarok or xine to play this file?)

Comment: "ls |sort -R | head -n1 | xargs amarok" does exactly what I need!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
find -iname '*/mp3' -print0 | rl -0 | xargs -r0 mplayer
```

As mentioned, `sort -R` has similar semantics to `rl`,

```
find -iname '*/mp3' -print0 | sort -z -R | xargs -r0 mplayer
```

Comment: This would work but "ls |sort -R | head -n1 | xargs amarok" does the trick -- and they're not all mp3 files, either, some are wav or wmv.  So this is more versatile.  (Though I'm assuming find -iname "*" -print0...etc. would work too?)  In any case, I'm all set.  Thanks!